# How to remove particular tag from XML file using Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, iis, powershell-ise, powershell-cmdlet

From below xml snippet I want to remove only "ConnectionString" tag from 
`<appSettings>` parent tag:

```
     <configuration>  
        <appSettings>
            <add key="ConnectionString" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
            <add key="ConnectionString1" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
            <add key="ConnectionString2" value=" Data Source=192.168.1.19;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Demo;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa;Password=powershell;Application Name=web;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200;"/>
          </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Please let me know how to do this using powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```powershell
# Set file path
$File = '.\config.xml'

# Get file contents as XML
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $File

# Find node with key="ConnectionString"
$Remove = $xml.appSettings.configuration.appSettings.add |
                Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'ConnectionString'}

# Remove this node from it's parent
$xml.appSettings.configuration.appSettings.RemoveChild($Remove) | Out-Null

# Save file
$xml.Save($File)
```

Comment: Thanks its worked for me. After removing Connection strings from appSettings tag. Still I have to select 30+ tags from appSettings tag and need to copy the selected tags to another xml file. Please let me know how to do this? Tags are having key values like, <add key="PassWord" value="1234"/>

Answer (score 2):

Removing is done by node's parent. First find the desired node and you'll get its parent via `ParentNode` property. Then via the parent, remove the child node via `RemoveChild()`. Like so,

```
[xml]$doc = cat 'path/to/xml'
$nodeToRemove = $doc.SelectSingleNode("//add[@key='ConnectionString']")
$parent = $nodeToRemove.ParentNode
$parent.RemoveChild($nodeToRemove)
$doc.Save([console]::out)
```

Comment: SelectSingleNode is not working in powershell 2.0? SoI have used like this $doc .configuration.appSettings.add | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'ConnectionString'}. While saving into file I am getting below error:Cannot convert value "System.Xml.XmlElement" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."At line:11 char:32
+  $parent = [xml] $nodeToRemove. <<<< ParentNode 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException